# JPA persist same entity twice

Tags: jpa, persistence, duplicates

I just noticed that a part of code I worked on saves the same entity twice.
I tried several tricks, like flush() and Transaction REQUIRES_NEW but nothing does it.
But I can see while debugging that after calling persist(entity), I get an ID (IDENTITY) for that entity... but just a bit later in the code if I look at the variables I'll see the same entity with a different ID and two itenties with those IDs in the Table.

This is using Java EE 6 with Glassfish 3.0.1

Comment: Please add some code of your entity and the code you use to persist it.

Comment: It's actually using code generated by Netbeans.

In this case I have a Servlet calling a session bean's method simply doing a 
getEntityManager().persist(entity);

So when I debug, just a few lines after my Servlet calls the session bean, I can see the entity's ID change and in the DB too.
And the part which I guess would be interesting in the entity:
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "MEMBER_ID")
    private Integer memberId;

Comment: Not possible to answer with the current level of details. Please provide some code, show at which point you "see" different IDs.

Comment: I can see it any other places in the Servlet after the call to the sesion bean. And the same entity is placed twice in the database, so there is no doubt JPA is placing it twice in the DB even though debugging shows me that I only call persist one once.

Answer (score 1):

What JPA provider are you using? and what version?

Enable logging (on finest) and include the log of what occurs.

If using EclipseLink to enable logging see,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

What value is assigned to your object's id, check to ensure it is  > 0.
Also ensure that you table in the database was generated with an IDENTITY column.
What database are you using?

Try using TABLE sequencing to see if it has to do with IDENTITY sequencing.

Also include the source code for you class.